# Why HAproxy is sending FIN to nginx Server in performance setup?

Tags: performance, nginx, tcp, websocket, haproxy

We have below setup for performance testing.

> WebSocket Client -> Nginx(Secure Websocket) -> HAProxy -> Backend
>   Server

Above setup works without any issue in normal testing.

When we load nginx with 100 new connections per second, after 8000-9000 connections , nginx sends 502 Bad Gateway for very few connection randomly with below error

> no live upstreams while connecting to upstream,

I debugged issue from tcpdump that haproxy is sending FIN element after finishing three way handshake.

It seems that there is no problem with backend server because When HAProxy is removed from setup it works fine with same load.

> WebSocket Client -> Nginx(Secure Websocket) -> Backend server  (Working one)

With same load(100 new connections/second) it works fine without any issue.

In which component there can be error ?

Comment: Having each component in same machine changes the # of open sockets, connections, # of files on the same machine. Try this setup with components split across machines and see if it helps

Comment: All components are in different machines and file.limit is already increased in all.

Comment: See if this helps you https://medium.com/@pawilon/tuning-your-linux-kernel-and-haproxy-instance-for-high-loads-1a2105ea553e

Comment: What are your maxconns values in haproxy ?

Comment: maxconns values in haproxy is 300000.